# Interact (get) a variable value from working Task<>

Tags: c#, task, progress

I am working on Windows Forms application, that needs to start a big amount of async tasks. In other words, a small control panel, that will start and monitor the process (Task), started from this UI control panel.

But, after some researches, I realized, that there is no easy way to monitor variables' values from inside the Task. 
Currently, I am looking for any way of monitoring progress in Task<>. Thinked, that I might start minimized process (Just basically copy&paste the whole code from task, that I need to start to a ConsoleApp, but, as always, that is not easy to catch the data from variables).

Any thoughts, how to do it correctly?

And found `IProgress` interface, but I didn't actually get the idea how it works. Just no examples.

Comment: _Just no examples._ There you go: [Reporting Progress from Async Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)

Comment: [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) This article is referenced from `IProgress` msdn page